# Hidden Adjacent CollectionViewCells are still active?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView with paging enabled in the storyboard. Each collection view cell is the full width of the screen

```
return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
```

I am trying to set up IAP and have encountered an Issue. Each cell has a button that checks for a product_ID associated with the row when tapped.

```
    print("About to fetch the product...")

    // Can make payments
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
    {
        let productID:NSSet! = NSSet(object: self.product_ID)
        let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
        print("Fetching Products")
    }else{
        print("Can't make purchases")
        UIAlertView(title: "Purchases Disabled",
                    message: "Purchases are disabled on your device! Enable Purchases in the Restriction Settings on your device.",
                    delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
    }
```

payment queue

```
 func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                  updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])

{
    print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                print("Product Purchased")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                // Handle the purchase
                print(product_ID)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: product_ID)
                setTitle = "Apply Theme"
            case .failed:
                print("Purchased Failed")
                setTitle = "4.99"
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
            case .restored:
                print("Already Purchased")
                //SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                // Handle the purchase
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: product_ID)
                setTitle = "Apply Theme"
            default:
                break
            }
            purchaseButton.setTitle(setTitle, for: .normal)
        }
    }

}
```

`

The issue I have is that when I press the button, it doesn't return 1 productID, it returns 3. It processes the payment for the cell I select ***and every adjacent cell.***. It seems that even when the other cells are off screen they are still active. They don't seem to be removed by the system. Is there a solution to this? I've never run into an issue like this before.

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem you have described. (But you should not call `restoreCompletedTransactions` in the `.restored` case; you will get an infinite loop). Where is the code that handles the button press and submits a payment?

Comment: OH h sorry! I've updated the question to hopefully provide more relevant code

Comment: You shouldn't request the product when the user taps the cell.  You should fetch all of your products when the app launches and use that to determine which cells are even in the collection view.